# SQL How to group by but with special conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have  a `SQL Server 2008` table where I have a list of employees with `timestamps`.

I have a script that groups by employee the dates.

What I need is to group by employee but I have to exclude the timestamps that are in the same day and the difference between them are **less than 8 hours**.

Here is a table that explains better:

[image]

I created a SQL Fiddle with the table and sample data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b956/1

> Any clue?

Comment: Your example looks more like an `order by` than a `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want is `lag()`, which is in SQL Server 2012+.  With `lag()`, you would do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(date) over (partition by EmployeeId order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where not (cast(prev_date as date) = cast(date as date) and
           date <= dateadd(hour, 8, prev_date)
          ) or
      prev_date is null;
```

In SQL Server 2008, you can do something similar with `outer apply`:

```
select t.*
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 prev.*
      from t prev
      where prev.Employee_id = t.EmployeeId and
            prev.date < t.date and
            cast(prev.date as date) = cast(t.date as date)
      order by prev.date desc
     ) prev
where prev.date is null or
      t.date > dateadd(hour, 8, prev.date);
```

You may need an `order by` to maintain the same ordering.

Comment: I get NULL's using the first script.

Comment: And there's no `order by` inside the `top 1` query. I know that was an accident.

Comment: @VAAA . . . The first shouldn't work because `lag()` isn't supported in SQL Server 2008.  I fixed the second with the `order by`.

Comment: @OP: SQL Fiddle appears to be running SQL Server 2014 even when you select SQL Server 2008 (`select @@version`). That might be why you actually got results with `lag`.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work by excluding rows for which there exist previuos row with diffrence less than 8 hours:

```
select p1.employeeid, count(*) as [count]
from punch p1
where not exists(select * from punch p2 
                 where p2.employeeid = p1.employeeid and p2.id < p1.id and
                 dateadd(hour, 8, p2.date) > p1.date)
group by p1.employeeid
```